# xUnit Async Test in Callback

Tags: c#, thread-safety, async-await, xunit

This is my current test. It succeeds, which it should obvious **not** do. How do I make this test fail?

```
[Fact]
public async Task ExecuteCallback()
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
    {
        new MyClassUnderTest((param) =>
        {
            Assert.Null(param);
            Assert.NotNull(param);
            timer.Stop();
        });
    };
    timer.Interval = 500;
    timer.Start();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

I want to test the inner logic of my class (how it executes the provided Action and its parameters), and especially it's behavior when it runs in a eventhandler since it does some tricky things with threads.

Comment: Why did you choose this method of testing in the first place? Why are you relying on a `Timer`?

Comment: I choose this way of testing because it is very close to the production problem I'm trying to solve. If I would have had any saying in the design in the first place, I probably would have other problems :). I also have no experience with async testing, so I just copied the code with the error. Left out all the code I don't want to test and inserted some Asserts. Any suggestion on how to do this better is appreciated.

Comment: There isn't anything "async" about your method. You're simply firing a `Timer` object. You don't need to mark your method `async Task` for that, as you're not awaiting anything. Does the timer elapse?

Comment: yes it does elapse, the code inside the body is executed, the assertation fails, but the test succeed.

Comment: I am also aware that the async task is overkill right now, but I think it is the direction to go. But I have no idea where the await keyword would make sense.

Comment: Do you actually invoke the delegate you pass somewhere?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes it is invoked. Currently that is the only thing that MyClassUnderTest does at this moment.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424071/nunit-asserts-in-separate-thread) is what you need.

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to test? Why do you need the `Timer`?

Comment: The event shares no synchronizationcontext with the rest of the code. The timer event might be executed on another thread. since we are **not** in a form (not even in the UI layer) we can't use a control as synchronisationobject neither can we make use of the 'InvokeRequiered' method. The goal of MyClassUnderTest is to provide the context and make sure the event is handled synchronous. The best way of simulating this behavior seems actually using a timer.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the `Timer` event handler runs on a different thread than the NUnit test.  The `thrown Exception` is **NOT** caught by NUnit, so the test succeeds.

Comment: Yes, this is all true. But it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Except for the fact that is says [Fact] and the exception is not caught by xUnit.

Comment: Assert.Null(..) / NotNull throws an exception when not satisfied. that is how the test framework know a test failed.